# How to get the opened port (firewall) of an instance in GCP using gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

For example, I have an instance named `test`, now I need to know which port is opened for this instance. How do I do it in command line using `gcloud`?

Not the port opened inside the instance, but the Firewall attached to this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to see the firewall rules associated with an instance using the cloud shell but in 2 steps. First, we have to run the following command to get the instance detail to see the firewall tags:
`gcloud compute instances describe instance-name`
In the output, you will see the firewall tags like the following:

[output of above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2qQQ.png)

then run the following command to see, to which firewall rule these tags are attached to.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list --format="table(name,network,
          direction,priority,sourceRanges.list():label=SRC_RANGES,
          destinationRanges.list():label=DEST_RANGES,
          allowed[].map().firewall_rule().list():label=ALLOW,
          denied[].map().firewall_rule().list():label=DENY,
          sourceTags.list():label=SRC_TAGS,
          sourceServiceAccounts.list():label=SRC_SVC_ACCT,
          targetTags.list():label=TARGET_TAGS,
          targetServiceAccounts.list():label=TARGET_SVC_ACCT,
          disabled
      )"
```

it will give the output like below:
[output of above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEEnb.png)

Answer (score 3):

Using Cloud Console, we can list your VM instances.  If we click on the vertical "three dots", we will find an entry that is called "View network details".  From there we see a panel that looks like:

[image]

This seems to show all the rules for the firewall for this VM instance.

Comment: I know how to do it on GCP console.. I need to use gcloud

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud SDK does not have a command for this requirement. You can use gcloud to list firewall-rules, you can use gcloud to list compute instances. You will have to apply external logic to map the two together.

Firewall rules are associated with compute engine instances via several methods:

- By a target tag
- By a service account
- For all instances in the network

Therefore, first display all of the compute engine instances, fetch each one's service account and tags. Then display all the firewall-rules, fetch the targets for each rule. Then match everything together and print a list of open ports for an instance, or all instances.

This is too complex a task for the CLI. You will either need to write a program to do this, or implement a script to process, sort and sync the CLI outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this questions is a bit old but I wanted to add a detailed answer that fully automates what you need, as I needed it as well. Hopefully others will find it useful.

As mentioned above, GCP firewall rules can be applied via three methods:

- Network tags
- Service accounts
- VPC membership

This data can be extracted via two different `gcloud` commands, but you must connect the dots between each individual compute instance and the three items I mention above.

I actually have a requirement to do this at work in order to generate nmap scripts that target instances with ports exposed to the public Internet. So I filter down a bit to include only instances that are running, have public IP addresses, and are correlated to firewall rules with a source range of `0.0.0.0/0`.

Here is how I do it.

First, I generate JSON files that are specifically formatted and filtered with the data I need. I use these two commands:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list \
    --format="json(name,allowed[].map().firewall_rule().list(),network,
        targetServiceAccounts.list(),targetTags.list())" \
    --filter="direction:INGRESS AND disabled:False AND
        sourceRanges.list():0.0.0.0/0 AND
        allowed[].map().firewall_rule().list():*" \
    | tee ./json-data/"$i"/firewall-rules.json


gcloud compute instances list \
    --format="json(name,networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[0].natIP,
        serviceAccounts[].email,tags.items[],networkInterfaces[].network)" \
    --filter="networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[0].type:ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
        AND status:running" \
    | tee ./json-data/"$i"/compute-instances.json
```

Then, I use this python script to process the the files generated above. It will create a directory in your CWD called `out-firewall-data` that contains three files:

- applied-rules.csv (instance,external_ip,allowed_tcp,allowed_udp)
- run-nmap.sh (a script to port scan them)
- run-masscan.sh (faster scanner for instances with 1-65535 exposed)

I'm hosting this script in a [GitLab repo here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-security/gl-redteam/gcp_firewall_enum/) and will probably continue development of it there. It also supports auditing many projects at once, you can view the instructions in the repository.

You can run this script like `gen_nmap.py --single /path/to/jsons/`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
Process gcloud output to determine applied firewall rules.

Firewall rules are applied via multiple methods and Google does not provide
an easy way to script what rules are actually applied to what compute
instances.

Please see the included README for detailed instructions.
"""

import glob
import sys
import os
import json
import argparse


def process_args():
    """Handles user-passed parameters"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    target = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    target.add_argument('--single', '-s', type=str, action='store',
                        help='Single directory containing json files.')
    target.add_argument('--multi', '-m', type=str, action='store',
                        help='Root directory contains multiple subdirectories'
                        ' of json files')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.single:
        target = os.path.abspath(args.single)
    else:
        target = os.path.abspath(args.multi)

    # Before moving on, validate all the input data is present
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        print("[!] That directory does not exist. Please try again.")
        sys.exit()

    return args

def parse_json(file):
    """
    Loads the json data from a file into memory
    """
    # If used in multi mode, there is a good chance we hit a lot of empty
    # or missing files. We'll return empty data on those so the program can
    # continue with the next directory.
    if not os.path.isfile(file):
        return {}

    with open(file, 'r') as infile:
        try:
            data = json.load(infile)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            return {}

    return data

def cleanup_rules(rules):
    """
    Extracts details from firewall rules for easier processing
    """
    clean_rules = []

    for rule in rules:
        name = rule['name']
        udp_ports = []
        tcp_ports = []

        if 'all' in rule['allowed']:
            tcp_ports = ['all']
            udp_ports = ['all']
        else:
            for ports in rule['allowed']:
                if 'tcp' in ports:
                    tcp_ports = [port.replace('tcp:', '') for port in ports.split(',')]
                if 'udp' in ports:
                    udp_ports = [port.replace('udp:', '') for port in ports.split(',')]

        # If a rule set has no target tags and no target svc account
        # then it is applied at the VPC level, so we grab that here.
        if 'targetServiceAccounts' not in rule and 'targetTags' not in rule:
            network = rule['network']
        # Otherwise, we are not interested in the network and can discard
        # it so that future functions will not think rules are applied
        # network-wide.
        else:
            network = ''

        # Tags and target svc accounts may or may not exist
        if 'targetTags' in rule:
            net_tags = rule['targetTags'].split(',')
        else:
            net_tags = []
        if 'targetServiceAccounts' in rule:
            svc_tags = rule['targetServiceAccounts'].split(',')
        else:
            svc_tags = []

        clean_rules.append({'name': name,
                            'tcp_ports': tcp_ports,
                            'udp_ports': udp_ports,
                            'net_tags': net_tags,
                            'svc_tags': svc_tags,
                            'network': network})
    return clean_rules

def cleanup_instances(instances):
    """
    Extracts details from instace data for easier processing
    """
    clean_instances = []

    for instance in instances:
        # The following values should exist for each instance due to the
        # gcloud filtering used.
        name = instance['name']
        networks = [interface['network'] for interface in instance['networkInterfaces']]
        external_ip = instance['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]['natIP']

        # The following values may or may not exist, it depends how the
        # instance is configured.
        if 'serviceAccounts' in instance:
            svc_account = instance['serviceAccounts'][0]['email']
        else:
            svc_account = ''
        if 'tags' in instance:
            tags = instance['tags']['items']
        else:
            tags = []

        clean_instances.append({'name': name,
                                'tags': tags,
                                'svc_account': svc_account,
                                'networks': networks,
                                'external_ip': external_ip})

    return clean_instances

def merge_dict(applied_rules, rule, instance):
    """
    Adds or updates final entries into dictionary

    Using a discrete function as several functions update this dictionary, so
    we need to check for the existence of a key and then decide to create or
    update it.
    """
    name = instance['name']

    if name in applied_rules:
        applied_rules[name]['allowed_tcp'].update(rule['tcp_ports'])
        applied_rules[name]['allowed_udp'].update(rule['udp_ports'])
    else:
        applied_rules[name] = {'external_ip': instance['external_ip'],
                               'allowed_tcp': set(rule['tcp_ports']),
                               'allowed_udp': set(rule['udp_ports'])}

    return applied_rules

def process_tagged_rules(applied_rules, rules, instances):
    """
    Extracts effective firewall rules applied by network tags on instances
    """
    for rule in rules:
        for instance in instances:
            for tag in rule['net_tags']:
                if tag in instance['tags']:
                    applied_rules = merge_dict(applied_rules, rule, instance)
    return applied_rules

def process_vpc_rules(applied_rules, rules, instances):
    """
    Extracts effective firewall rules applied by VPC membership
    """
    for rule in rules:
        for instance in instances:
            # In the cleaning function, we only applied a network tag if the
            # rule is applied to the whole VPC. So a match means it applies.
            if rule['network'] and rule['network'] in instance['networks']:
                applied_rules = merge_dict(applied_rules, rule, instance)

    return applied_rules

def process_svc_rules(applied_rules, rules, instances):
    """
    Extracts effective firewall rules applied by service accounts
    """
    for rule in rules:
        if rule['svc_tags']:
            for instance in instances:
                if instance['svc_account'] in rule['svc_tags']:
                    applied_rules = merge_dict(applied_rules, rule, instance)

    return applied_rules

def process_output(applied_rules):
    """
    Takes the python dictionary format and output several useful files
    """
    if not applied_rules:
        print("[!] No publicly exposed ports, sorry!")
        sys.exit()

    print("[*] Processing output for {} instances with exposed ports"
          .format(len(applied_rules)))

    out_dir = 'out-firewall-data'
    if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
        os.makedirs(out_dir)

    # First, write the raw data in CSV
    with open(out_dir + '/applied-rules.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("name,external_ip,allowed_tcp,allowed_udp\n")
        for i in applied_rules:
            outfile.write("{},{},{},{}\n"
                          .format(i,
                                  applied_rules[i]['external_ip'],
                                  applied_rules[i]['allowed_tcp'],
                                  applied_rules[i]['allowed_udp'])
                          .replace("set()", ""))

    # Next, make an nmap script
    nmap_tcp = 'nmap --open -Pn -sV -oX {}-tcp.xml {} -p {}\n'
    nmap_tcp_common = 'nmap --open -Pn -sV -oX {}-tcp.xml {}\n'
    nmap_udp = 'sudo nmap --open -Pn -sU -sV -oX {}-udp.xml {} -p {}\n'
    nmap_udp_common = 'sudo nmap --open -Pn -sU -sV -oX {}-udp.xml {} -F\n'

    with open(out_dir + '/run-nmap.sh', 'w') as outfile:
        for name in applied_rules:
            external_ip = applied_rules[name]['external_ip']

            # "All" as a rule will apply to both TCP and UDP. These get special
            # nmap commands to do only the common ports (full range is too slow
            # and will be handled with masscan commands.
            if set(['all']) in applied_rules[name].values():
                outfile.write("echo running common TCP/UDP scans against {}\n"
                              .format(name))
                outfile.write(nmap_tcp_common.format(name, external_ip))
                outfile.write(nmap_udp_common.format(name, external_ip))

            else:
                if applied_rules[name]['allowed_tcp']:
                    ports = ','.join(applied_rules[name]['allowed_tcp'])
                    outfile.write("echo running TCP scans against {}\n"
                                  .format(name))
                    outfile.write(nmap_tcp.format(name, external_ip, ports))

                if applied_rules[name]['allowed_udp']:
                    ports = ','.join(applied_rules[name]['allowed_udp'])
                    outfile.write("echo running UDP scans against {}\n"
                                  .format(name))
                    outfile.write(nmap_udp.format(name, external_ip, ports))

    # Now, write masscan script for machines with all TCP ports open
    masscan = 'sudo masscan -p{} {} --rate=1000 --open-only -oX {}.xml\n'
    with open(out_dir + '/run-masscan.sh', 'w') as outfile:
        for name in applied_rules:
            external_ip = applied_rules[name]['external_ip']

            if set(['all']) in applied_rules[name].values():
                outfile.write("echo running full masscan against {}\n"
                              .format(name))
                outfile.write(masscan.format('1-65535', external_ip, name))

    print("[+] Wrote some files to {}, enjoy!".format(out_dir))


def main():
    """
    Main function to parse json files and write analyzed output
    """
    args = process_args()

    applied_rules = {}
    rules = []
    instances = []

    # Functions below in a loop based on whether we are targeting json files
    # in a single directory or a tree with multiple project subdirectories.
    if args.multi:
        targets = glob.glob(args.multi + '/*')
    else:
        targets = [args.single]

    for target in targets:
        rules = parse_json(target + '/firewall-rules.json')
        instances = parse_json(target + '/compute-instances.json')

        if not rules or not instances:
            print("[!] No valid data in {}".format(target))
            continue

        # Clean the data up a bit
        rules = cleanup_rules(rules)
        print("[*] Processed {} firewall rules in {}"
              .format(len(rules), target))

        instances = cleanup_instances(instances)
        print("[*] Processed {} instances in {}"
              .format(len(instances), target))

        # Connect the dots and build out the applied rules dictionary
        applied_rules = process_tagged_rules(applied_rules, rules, instances)
        applied_rules = process_vpc_rules(applied_rules, rules, instances)
        applied_rules = process_svc_rules(applied_rules, rules, instances)

    # Process data and create various output files
    process_output(applied_rules)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```